# Ember DS.RecordArray filter items

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am getting all the records in my route model call, but then in one of the components I only want to show a subset of the records. I am doing this by calling `models.filter(somefilter)`. The problem with this is that `filter` returns an `Array` not a `DS.RecordArray` and when some action causes a model to be removed from the store, the `Array` is not updated and the component with that model is not removed.

Does anyone know how to either create a filter that returns a `DS.RecordArray` or convert an existing array into a `DS.RecordArray`.

```
// routes/index.js
Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('user');
  }
});

//index.hbs
{{some-component users=model}}

//some-component.js
Component.extend({
  filteredUsers: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('users').filter(...);
  })
});

//some-component.hbs
{{#each filteredUsers as |user|
  {{other-component user=user}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filteredUsers: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('users').filter(...);
  })
```

This will be executed only once.so whenever `users` property changed then `filteredUsers` will not be recalculated so it will not be up to date. In this case you need to introduce dependent property so that it will be recalculated whenever the dependent changed.

```
filteredUsers: Ember.computed('users',function() {
        return this.get('users').filter(...);
      })
```